# Submitting an Ionic App to Apple App Store without a Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have built my Ionic app with "ionic build ios" using my Windows 10 PC, I have a developer account with Apple.

Can I submit my ios build direct to Apple without using XCode or a Mac at all?

There seems to be many conflicting views regarding this online that Ionic has the ability to do this, whether Mac hardware alongside XCode is actually required to get a App in the Apple App Store.

Comment: This is specific to Ionic, which many claim doesn't require a Mac(Xcode) for iOS submissions

Comment: please post ref, i only know cordova doing that and that too in a paid plan

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Ionic Package](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/package-overview) service by signing up for [Ionic Platform](http://ionic.io/platform). It is for free as long as it is in beta.

You'll still need a service like [AppStore Uploader](https://appstoreuploader.com/) to upload the created `.ipa` file though, which usually don't come for free...

Comment: It doesn't seem to submit the apps to the apple store

Comment: So the "Ionic Package Service" does the part that Xcode would usually do on the Mac(creates the .ipa) and creates that file ready for submission to the App Store?

Comment: Will do the package, but you still need a mac to upload it, you can rent on on macincloud

Comment: @jcesarmobile It doesn't, but it creates an `.ipa` file that you can submit to the App Store.

Comment: So, you need a mac to submit it, so your answer is wrong. You can use phonegap build to package apps too

Comment: @jcesarmobile There are several services out there that will allow you to upload an `.ipa` file to the App Store without the need of a Mac... Will add this info to my answer. Phonegap build is also a solution, but has problems with a lot of cordova plugins afair..

Answer (score -1):

MacInTheCloud also offers an alternative option should you really need to bypass the Ionic Package Service and use XCode